# chan_ss7 error: installation error with asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk, ss7

I am trying to install chan_ss7 version chan_ss7-2.2.0 with asterisk-11.12.0... It shows me following error,     make: *** No rule to make target `../usr/src/asterisk-11.12.0/ /main/lock.o', needed by`mtp3d'.  Stop ,Any idea regarding this? Please guide... Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to install asterisk -11 on Ubuntu, then follow the guide below to complete installation without any issue.

Remember to replace the dahdi and libpri download links with current versions.

http://asterisk-rd.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/instalacion-paso-paso-de-asterisk-18-en.html

Comment: I am installing asterisk 11 on centos, and successfully installed..Issue is with installation of chan_ss7 or libss7. While installing chan_ss7 it show me the error "No rule to make target ../usr/src/asterisk-11.12.0/ /main/lock.o', needed bymtp3d'. Stop"

Comment: well, I was going through some stuff related to ss7 and found this may be it could help you. link is given at the end for further details.                                                           In order to use libss7, you must get at least the following versions of DAHDI and Asterisk:
DAHDI:2.0.x
libss7:trunk (currently, there only is a trunk release).
Asterisk:1.6.x
You must then do a `make; make install` in each of the directories that you installed in the given order(DAHDI first, libss7 second, and Asterisk last)[link](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Signaling+System+Number+7)

Comment: In the past, there was a special asterisk-ss7 branch to use which contained the SS7 code. That code has been merged back into the trunk version of Asterisk, and the old asterisk-ss7 branch has been deprecated and removed. If you are still using the asterisk-ss7 branch, it will not work against the current version of libss7, and you should switch to asterisk-trunk instead

Answer (score 0):

I got it to install, by editing the makefile to point the Asterisk 11 directory, to the source of asterisk 11.

in my case

ASTERISK_PATH=../certified-asterisk-11.6-cert7

it was

ASTERISK_PATH=../source/telephony/asterisk or something like that. You should be fine if you just point it to the right directory.

I hope it helps.